# How to use enum values as available values for variable?

Tags: angular, typescript

For example, I have enum and want to use its values for variable. So other values cannot be used. Is it possible in TypeScript?

```
enum FormType {
   Create = 1,
   Update = 2
}

// something like that
const a: FormType = FormType.Create // so for example 3 cannot be used

// or something like that
const a: FormType.Create | FormType.Update = FormType.Create
```

Answer (score 2):

You are already doing it right - you declare the enum and use it as a type. However, this will only help while Programming.

Whenever the code is transpiled, typescript will create a javascript Object out of it and there are no integrated "checks" on runtime. If you need to validate, you need to manually check if the type is included in the enum - for example with

```js
if(!Object.values(Formtype).includes(value)) throw new Error('Wrong type for enum');
```

Comment: But it doesn't work. I still can define any number as a value of my variable. In both cases from my question. Thank you.